# Generating diff based on versions

Tags: database, diff, versioning, synchronization

The scenario is that I have a MySQL DB on the server side, whose content is regularly updated/changed and I have 5-10 Linux clients... each of which would have a copy of the DB, and would need to have a significant portion of the DB in memory. 
I want to be able to get what version the client has, and then send the latest-updated data through a diff. Database entries may get added/removed/updated. I need to explore best possible ways of doing this, and I am looking for valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with Open Source DiffKit, if you are able to use Java in your configuration:

http://www.diffkit.org